# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /app.properties: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)

Tags: android, file-io, properties-file

I would like to create file of format `.properties` in android app. Unfortunately, I am getting  error  java.io.FileNotFoundException: /app.properties: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system) Any idea why?

Comment: can you show a little from your code ?

Comment: and also check that you gave WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in manifest..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use "android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" insert it to AndroidManifest.xml
example's below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.megazy.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: This answer is utterly false - **There is no such permision**

Comment: Yes there is no such permission, WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE. This should not be marked as correct-answer.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you cannot write to a file called

```
 /app.properties
```

as that would be located in the top-level or root directory of the device, to which application code will never have write access.

See the [Saving Files](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) section of the developer docs to learn about valid places to store a file, and which do **and do not** require additional *attainable* permissions.